# WPF MahApps Change style of Window notworking for elements inside its UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, mahapps.metro

I added `MahApps` resources like in **App.xaml:**

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />

            <!-- accent resource -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/blue.xaml" />

            <!-- theme resource -->
            <!-- change "BaseLight" to the theme you want -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/basedark.xaml" />              

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ....
```

It works well on all of my windows but i have a special window (`WindowA`) that i want be in a different color so i added the `MahApps` resources to this window

**WindowA.xaml:**

```
    <controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />

            <!-- accent resource -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/blue.xaml" />

            <!-- theme resource -->
            <!-- change "BaseLight" to the theme you want -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/basedark.xaml" />              

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

Now i want apply my accent color dynamically to it, so i use some codes like this:

```
ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(appOrWindow,
         ThemeManager.GetAccent("Amber"),
         ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("basedark"));
```

The result is cool for title bar color (`Amber` color) of the `WindowA` **BUT** i have a `label` (`Lable 1`) in a `UserControl` (`TestUserControl`) inside `WindowA` and its color is `Blue` yet!

> WindowA > TestUserControl > Lable 1

[image]

The `lable 1` xaml tag inside `TestUserControl`:

```
 <Label Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}">Lable1</Label>
```

I want change all element colors with `{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}` `Foreground` color to `Amber` include all elements inside `UserControls` of the `WindowA` with `AccentColorBrush` `StaticResource`.

I think the `UserControl` is using `MahApps` resources `declared` in `App.xaml`. How can i force it to use `MahApps` resources `declared` in `WindowA.xaml`.

How can i fix this?

---

**Edit1**

If i apply an accent like `Red` to the `Application` the `label 1` color will be changed to the `Red` color.

Comment: Have you pasted wrong code for WindowA.xaml? It has Accents/blue.xaml should this be Accents/amber.xaml?

Comment: The result is same...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the UserControl.Resources

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/amber.xaml" />
```

Comment: there is not any different in result when i use `blue.xaml` or between `amber.xaml`. But if have not any resource of `Accent color` between my window resources, my `ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle` will not work then i use one of MahApps colors resource file like `blue.xaml`. Anyway the lable color is Blue in all states!

Comment: If i add the `Accents/amber.xaml` resource manually to the `TestUserControl` then my `Lable1` color will be changed to amber color but my question is how i can change this colors dynamically when i change the `WindowA Accent` by using `ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DynamicResource` instead `StaticResource` for the foreground.

```
<Label Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">Lable1</Label>
```

Hope that helps.